# Firebase security when user does not control email address they sign up as

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore

A scenario:

- I store sensitive data in Firestore with these security rules:

  ```
  A. allow read: if resource.data.email == request.auth.token.email;

  B. allow read: if resource.data.email == request.auth.token.email && request.auth.token.email_verified == true;
  ```
- A malicious user Bob downloads my JavaScript app and uses client-side calls to create an account with the email "x@example" they don't control and a password of their choice without email verification. Bob is now logged in.
- A legitimate user Alice wants to create an account for their own email address "x@example", perform email verification and read from Firestore.

Questions:

1. Directly after Bob signs up, will he be able to read data in Firestore that passes security rule A?
2. Directly after Bob signs up, will he be able to read data in Firestore that passes security rule B?
3. When Alice tries to sign up, will she be prevented from doing so because Bob has already created an account with that email address? If so, how is Alice suppose to sign up?
4. Once Alice is signed up (I'm guessing you have to force her to do a password reset), will Bob still be signed in? If so, can he read data that passes security rule A and B?

Comment: Have you tried this yourself?

Comment: I've experimented but I'd like to robustly understand how I'm suppose to protect again Bob spoofing Alice's email address instead of guessing, getting it wrong and the reputation of my app being damaged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes
2. No
3. Yes. But you can give her the option to send a password reset email. Given that Alice has access to the mailbox, she can use that to reset the password.
4. Bob will remain signed in until his ID token needs to be refreshed, or until the system otherwise forces a refresh. At that point, he will need to enter the new password, which he can't know.

Comment: Thanks. With 4, how do we practically stop Bob from reading Alice's data which I tried to secure with rule B then? Can I force a refresh when the password is reset?  It sounds like you're saying Bob will pass rule B after Alice does the password reset until a refresh happens which is obviously a big security hole unless I change something.

Comment: Is the part I'm missing here is that you should be securing user data by matching against the auth.uid (which can't be spoofed) instead of the email address (which can be spoofed)?